# How can I do an exact match exclusion on a full string with a .NET regular expression?

Tags: .net, regex

I need a .NET regular expression that matches anything *other* than the exact full string match specified. So basically:

```
^Index$
```

... is the only exclusion I care about. Strings can start with, finish with or contain "Index", but not match exactly.

The answer *must* be via the pattern itself, as I am passing an argument to a third-party library and do not have control over the process other than via the Regex pattern.

Comment: Can you provide more information?  I.e., why regular expressions?  You could achieve this more simply with a `myString != "Index"` comparison, and then you don't need to worry about regexes.

Comment: I have to pass an argument to something that takes a regular expression to match something else. I don't have any control over how that thing works other than, "match or don't match according to this regex"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
^(?!Index$)
```

Comment: Yep, this works better. It's so obvious now that I think about it!

Answer (score 4):

If a regular expression is a must,

```csharp
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^Index$");

if (!match.Success){
    // Do something
}
```

And with a horrible way

```csharp
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^(.*(?<!Index)|(?!Index).*)$");

if (match.Success){
    // Do something
}
```

<sub>Note: the second one is not tested, and the regular expression engine needs to support full look ahead and look behind.</sub>

Comment: There is a simpler and faster way than the second, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `if (!r.Match("^Index$").Success) ...`.

Comment: No, it has to be in the regular expression syntax. The only control I have over what I'm doing here is via the pattern itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `!regex.Match.Success`.